# Creates a duplicate of an input field when focused in android 4.0 webview using jquery mobile and phonegap

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing a phonegap application with webview. But when focus is on any input textbox a duplicate of the textbox is created automatically and whatever I enter will be within this textbox. On focus out, this value is shown in the default textbox. I had tried to avoid this by following ways:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

But no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use...

`input[type="text"]:not(.selectbox), input[type="number"], input[type="password"] {
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    outline-style: none;
}`